# Swift Custom cell to fit screen width

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, custom-cell

I'm using custom cell in TableView and my problem is the cell content isn't 100% screen width. The Xcode asks me every time to set a fixed width.

My cell looks like that:
[image: StackView cell]

[image: Cell container]

With StackView to keep content together.
I added constraints to keep both StackViews and Slider clipped to a container.

And when I'm running my app the cell looks like crap:
[image: app view]

With only two constraints on vertical StackView (and not width set) it looks like that:
[image]
[image]

How to fit the cell to match the screen view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was causing the issue.
I miss clicked probably and added my CustomCell class for not only a cell but also for ContentView of that cell. 
That didn't invoke any issue at all - neither warnings nor fatal errors.
So I switched ContentView to default class and everything works perfectly for that cell.